# Is Tanach Simanim reliable from an Orthodox point of view?

Tags: tanach, orthodox, publications

I know that Judaism (or at least Orthodox Judaism) relies on the Masoretic Text. I saw that the publisher of the Tanach Simanim is Feldheim. I don't know if it is from an Orthodox point of view and if any Orthodox Rabbi would recommend it ?

Comment: Yes Feldheim is a very reliable Orthodox publisher

Comment: It's an ok text that's well typeset. AFAIK it doesn't have a translation or anything. What point-of-view issues are you worried about?

Comment: I heard from an expert that it is purity good but it has a few mistakes

Comment: @DoubleAA I found about Tanach Simanim only few days ago and I heard of Feldheim only recently. So I wanted to make sure there is no mistakes in its Hebrew text and on which codex it rely on.

Comment: Found a mistake in a Tanakh Simanim this morning (Psalms 148:5)

Comment: @DoubleAA  You wrote "Found a mistake in a Tanakh Simanim this morning (Psalms 148:5)" <-- can you elaborate on that? thanks

Comment: @barlop they marked a dechi instead of a tarcha on Hu, at least in my edition

Comment: @DoubleAA   Mine has a tipcha/tarcha  https://i.imgur.com/4gJyxcf.png    My one  looks like this 
 https://www.amazon.com/Tanach-Simanim-Hebrew-only-Feldheim/dp/B0035F4CCY     and re publication date, it says copyright 2008

Comment: @barlop no that's a dechi. Simanim prints dechi more bold than tarcha. Also dechi is printed at the beginning of the word whereas tarcha would be printed on the middle of the accented letter (like yetiv vs mahpach in prose books). See how they print a tarcha on וחרב פיפיות בידם

Answer (score 7):

**The Tanakh Simanim is based for the most part on the Aleppo Codex**, and where this version is lacking, on the Leningrad Codex. (see footnote 9 [here](http://etzion.org.il/vbm/english/archive/tanakh/07e-tanakh.htm#_ftn9)). As such it is an authoritative version that you can rely on.

In addition Feldheim is a well-known Orthodox publishing house with an excellent reputation.

Be aware though that the [Feldheim edition](http://www.feldheim.com/tanach-simanim-hebrew-only.html) is Hebrew-only. Depending on your needs, an alternative version (e.g., [Artscroll](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899062693.html) or [Koren](https://korenpub.com/koren/intusd/tanakh/tanakh-bible.html)) might be more practical.

Comment: "Based on" is being used quite loosely. As but one striking example, Simanim doesn't even mention the variant of ויהיו in Gen 9:29 even though that's what [the Leningrad Codex has](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d4/Leningrad-codex-01-genesis.pdf/page9-1275px-Leningrad-codex-01-genesis.pdf.jpg). Similarly with regards Trop, in Exodus 18:5 Simanim has a Zakef while [Leningrad has a Revi'i](http://tanakh.us/Server.html?Ex18:5-18:5).

Comment: I have the Artscroll English Tanach yet I couldn't find (or I am searching in a wrong way) a Hebrew Version. I know about English Hebrew interlinear Artscroll Chumash. Nevertheless, I prefer a complete Tanach.

Comment: @mil artscroll tanach is [here](http://www.amazon.com/Tanach-Stone-Student-Hebrew-English/dp/1578191122/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1463486925&sr=8-1&keywords=artscroll+tanach) in smaller size - there are different editions, see [artscroll site](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/BSV.html) for details, e.g., [here](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899062693.html) in black